# Firefox can't resize window in KDE (KUbuntu 18.04)

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, kde, window, resize

There's a known bug in Firefox in which the window cannot be resized, see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1461280. This is supposedly closed however I am experiencing it on KUbuntu 18.04 LTS with up to date Firefox 111.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1.
(Has the bug regressed?)

There is a known solution:

> Steps to fix:
>
> 1. Open Firefox
> 2. Menu -> More Tools -> Customize toolbar...
> 3. Check "Title Bar" option.
> 4. Try to resize the window with cursor on border.

**My Question:**

How do I best fix this automatically for all users as the default on a system?

Reason: We have over 100 lab computers still running Ubuntu 18.04. We can't upgrade them at this point in time (we will later but cannot not now due to tests), and would like to fix this error for all users.

Options:

- Right now I can only think of creating a default Firefox profile with the desired settings, then assign that to the 'skel' for all new user logins. Then nuke all existing users in labs (yes, that's ok in these labs).

Comment: We've ended up having to move to Google Chrome for the following 3 reasons: 1) Firefox for Linux didn't support Yubikey + Pin.  2) the latest Ubuntu packages use snap and refuses any user profile outside /home and this breaks our setup.  3) this browser resize bug

Comment: See a stopgap way around this here: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9y8dog/no_possibility_to_resize_my_firefox_windows_when/?avatarId=random&username=FarExcuse2825

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Been annoyed by this for months now.